# Serv-U FTP Server closes session while renaming file

Tags: c#, ftp

I try to move a file on our FTP server with the following C# code:

```
try  {
  FtpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sourcefile) as FtpWebRequest;
  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw);
  request.UseBinary = true;
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
  request.RenameTo = "/OtherFolder/newFileName";
  request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException e) {
  log.writeError("Error while moving " + file + " on " + downloadServer + " !");
  log.writeError(((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
  log.writeError(e.Message);
}
```

This used to work perfectly fine and actually still works if I run it on my local machine but if I run it on a server the files are not moved.

The Serv-U log shows (I added English translation to the german lines):

```
[02] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) Verbunden zu (connected to) xxx.xxx.61.245 (lokale Adresse (local address) xxx.xxx.63.243, Anschluss 21)
[21] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) 220 Serv-U FTP Server v12.1 ready...
[20] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) USER ABC
[21] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) 331 User name okay, need password.
[20] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) PASS **********
[02] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) Benutzer "ABC" angemeldet (User "ABC" connected)
[21] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) 230 User logged in, proceed.
[20] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) OPTS utf8 on
[21] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) 200 OPTS UTF8 is set to ON.
[20] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) PWD
[21] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) 257 "/C:/FTP/xxx" is current directory.
[20] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) CWD /C:/FTP/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/
[21] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) 250 Directory changed to /C:/FTP/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx
[20] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) RNFR Filename.zip
[21] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) 350 File or directory exists, ready for destination name.
[02] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) Sitzung geschlossen (Session closed)
[02] Wed 10Feb16 18:33:30 - (023490) Benutzer "ABC" abgemeldet (User ABC disconnected)
```

In short: The session closes while the server waits for the "RNTO". Is there any reason why my code could cause the session to close? Why does it work perfectly fine if executed on my machine but not on the server?
Downloading and Uploading from and to the same server works fine as well.

The "Documentation" for Serv-U is not really helpful:
[Link](http://www.serv-u.com/respcode.asp?cmd=RNFR&prod=su)

Edit: I added my Catch block.

The StatusDescription is "350 File or directory exists, ready for destination name."

The e.Message is "Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unbekannter Fehler beim Empfangen.." (    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive)
The Microsoft link to the error: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826210

The files are not that big and downloading/uploading works fine...

Comment: I feel silly to ask but are you sure that no `WebException` could have been inadvertly swallowed by your `try/catch` block?

Comment: I added the catch block and log output to the question